# How do I change the default audio track of an MKV file?

Tags: audio, video, matroska

I have an MKV video file that has two audio tracks, a Hindi-language track and an English-language track.  I guess the Hindi track is set as the default track.  I have a video player that doesn't allow you to select different audio tracks, so it only plays the Hindi one.

So my question is, how can I change the default audio track to the English one?  I found [this tool](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvpropedit.html#mkvpropedit.examples) that allows you to do it, but it's a command-line tool.  Are there any GUI tools that achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 20):

its not only CLI. here you can download GUI: https://www.fosshub.com/MKVToolNix.html 
and this is how you use it:

- select tracks
- set desired tracks as deafult
- mux it all

[image]

btw, you should consider to have new media player: https://potplayer.daum.net/

Comment: is there a way to do it for multiple file at once

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but for anyone that also wonders about this, there is a better GUI than mkvtoolnix to do this.
JMkvpropedit lets you do all mkvtoolnix does with a better user interface.

Can be downloaded from here: [JMkvpropedit's Doom9 topic](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=163753)

[image: Editing subtitle tracks]

[image: Editing attachments]

This is what the author says you can do with JMkvpropedit:

> For now you can:
>
> -Set title; default, forced, track name and language of video, audio and subtitle tracks (it was compiled for maximum of 30 tracks of each kind, I don't think it's needed, but can be changed easily on the source).
>
> -For title and track names there's a basic numbering function, where you specify the starting number and the padding.
>
> -You can set the path for mkvtoolnix now.
>
> -It's possible to just get the command line instead of actually editing the files.
>
> -You can add extra command line parameters for general and each track.